# CodeIgniter htaccess for subdomain without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have been searching this but could not find the answer. I might have missed something here. Basically I have two applications under one CI installation. Each of the app will have their own subdomain. So for example `http://foo.example.com/` which will redirect to `http://example.com/foo` and `http://bar.example.com/` which will redirect to `http://example.com/bar`. The `http://example.com/` itself will be some kind of a landing page.

The redirect part is working fine. But it keeps changing the URL from `http://foo.example.com/` to `http://example.com/foo`, which I want to prevent. I have read a solution to use a [P] instead of [L] flag, but that will require me to enable proxy.

Is there any other option for me to do this other than enabling proxy?

Currently my htaccess file is as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# The line for subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: does your domain have it's own `cgi` initialization or it's just a folder, although I'm not sure if this is relevant!

Comment: I don't understand what `cgi` is, I am noob in this field. Googled it and not sure what does it mean.

Comment: achieving it using proxy is very simple if you have access to virtual host file..not wanting to use proxy is just a personal reason or its a requirement ?